# Sitefinity Page dashboard show an advanced field [Allow search engines to index this page] in the grid

Tags: sitefinity

In the back end Sitefinity Page dashboard i need to show an advanced field [Allow search engines to index this page] in the grid.
Is it possible to customize the page grid? I know about adding field for dynamic content but doesn't have knowledge for adding field of sitefinity objects

Comment: No comment by the user who voted it negative

Answer (score 0):

I have never extended the grid for pages but I have for Events following this blog post, it may be of help to you: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/team-blog/2012/01/22/extending_the_built-in_content_modules

Comment: Thx Ben. But it looks for the simple task it require quite an effort. May be some body else knows if there some thing simpler for page dashboard as it is widely used.